# Setting FontSize on Button's ContentPresenter changes vertical alignment of text - XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, togglebutton

I have a ToggleButton custom control which changes the text and size when toggled. I can change/set fonts and change the background/foreground properties and it works fine.

But as soon as I set the FontSize property of the ContentPresenter the text in the button gets misaligned! Specifically the vertical position seems to be off (Moves way down in the button)

I can't figure out what's causing this. If I don't set the fontsize everything works as intended. Here is my button.

```
<Style x:Key="PlusSelectedToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF3498DB" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">           
                <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                         VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"

                                          />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" TargetName="Border" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" TargetName="Border" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Black" TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Selected" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="DarkGray" TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="75" TargetName="Border" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" TargetName="Border" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="+"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="50" TargetName="ContentPresenter"/>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF3498DB" />
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="40"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="White" TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Update:** I got it to work but I still don't fully understand why I have to do this.

```
   <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
           <Setter Property="Content" Value="+"/>
           <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="White" TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
           <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="27" TargetName="ContentPresenter"/>
           <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="Thin"></Setter>
           <Setter Property="TextBlock.Height" Value="40" TargetName="ContentPresenter"/>
           <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF3498DB" />
           <Setter Property="Width" Value="35"/>
           <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"/>                            
</Trigger>
```

I had to set the *TextBlock.Height* property to a much larger value (even larger then button height) to get the text to center vertically. Horizontally it stays at the same place. I'm not sure why it behaves like this.

Comment: You are setting FontSize 50 and Height is 40 and ContentAlignment is Center . It obviously will go out of ContentPresenter. Either increase the height or reduce the fontsize.

Comment: Thank you @ethicallogics! Having the font size larger than height was definitely one of the issues. I'm still confused as to why I have to do what I did to get it to align. See Update.